# Error Object Required in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Could some one please show me reason why I got error 'object required' when running this code in VBA? Sorry this is my first time writing a VBA code ..

```
    Public Sub FinalScore()
Dim E1, E2, E3, E4, GP, FE As Long
Dim strOutput, G As String
Dim S As Double
Dim Fail, Pass, Merit, Distinction As String

   E1 = InputBox("What is your result of 1st excecise?", "question1")
If Not IsNumeric(E1.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Sorry bro I need a number not a String"
    E1.SetFocus
Else
    If E1 < 0 And E1 > 10 Then
    MsgBox ("Input number must be in between 0 and 10")
    E1.SetFocus
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`E1` is type `Variant` and currently holds the *result* of the `InputBox` function, which returns a string generally. Since it is *not* an Object, it will raise an error on `E1.Value` and also on `E1.SetFocus`, because it doesn't have any such method or property.

The `.SetFocus` method pertains to `Form Control` objects and will not return the user to the input box.

You can use a `GoTo` Statement to control flow and force the user to input correct type/value:

```
ReTry:
   E1 = InputBox("What is your result of 1st excecise?", "question1")
If Not IsNumeric(E1) Then
    MsgBox "Sorry bro I need a number not a String"
    GoTo ReTry
Else
    If E1 < 0 And E1 > 10 Then
    MsgBox ("Input number must be in between 0 and 10")
    GoTo ReTry
    End If
End If
```

Note also that your variables are implicitly typed as `Variant`. In the following example, only `z` is strongly typed as a `String` data type. THe others do not have an explicit type, so they will be treated as `Variant`.

```
Dim x, y, z as String
```

It is recommended and good practice to type each variable:

```
Dim x as String
Dim y as String
Etc...
```

Comment: In addition, why do i get the error 'Invalid qualifier' at E1.Value when I compile the code?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct @DavidZemens, its been a while.

Comment: @TrungBún please re-read my answer. `E1` is not an object, so you can't do `E1.Value`.

Comment: @TrungBún because E1 is a variant. It doesn't have a property called Value!! You are using E1 as if it was like a control, module or class with property called value.

Comment: @JeremyThompson noted w/r/t the `GoTo` statement. Use with caution :-) but in this case, for someone who has literally never done VBA before (as OP admits), I am not going to try to explain how to wrap the `InputBox` call in a custom function!